# Inequality relationships removing unknowns

Tags: inequality

Assume we have a finite collection of real values $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ each between 0 and 1, and their sum less than 1. The same for the set $b$.

The inequality

$$\frac{a_i}{x} > \frac{b_i}{y} \quad (*)$$

must hold for all $i$, with both $x$ and $y$ also between 0 and 1. Is there a test I can do on the set $a$ and $b$ to guarantee (*), without any knowledge of $x$ or $y$?

An incorrect thought was to divide two different labeled inequalities producing

$$\frac{a_i}{a_j} > \frac{b_i}{b_j} $$

which must hold for ordered ${i,j}$ ($a_i > a_j$), but that too also didn't work.

Comment: No. For any such $a,b$ I can select $x=a_1, y =b_1$, or worse, and violate the condition $*$.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure if this clarification helps. $a,b,x,y$ are all fixed values. I also just realized I know $y$, the only thing don't know is $x$. Not trying to solve for $x$, but a test to determine if (*) holds for all $i$ given that unknown x and known y and sets a b.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $a_i, b_i, y , x \in (0,1)$.

If $\max_i\frac{b_i}{ya_i}\le 1$, then we have (*) holds since $\frac1x>1\ge\max_i\frac{b_i}{ya_i}$ would implies that for all $i$, $$\frac{a_i}x>\frac{b_i}{y}$$

However, if $\max_i\frac{b_i}{ya_i} > 1$, then we can't conclude as it is possible to have a small $x$ such that the inequality holds but at the same time it is possible to have $x$ that is not small enough.